# How to recover missing structures?

Tags: box2d, emscripten

This question is regarding Box2D v2.2.1 in JavaScript (compiled via Emscripten).

Some structs like `b2Vec2` and `b2BodyDef` work perfectly fine.

I can create instances of both, like so:

```
new Box2D.b2Vec2(0,0); // returns b2Vec {..} 
new Box2D.b2BodyDef(); // returns b2BodyDef {..}
```

However, other structs such as `b2MassData` and `b2Manifold` do not, observe:

```
new Box2D.b2MassData(); // Error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
new Box2D.b2Manifold(); // Error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
```

This leads to strange behavior when dealing with classes which use these structs:

```
// Setup
gravity = new Box2D.b2Vec2( 0, 10 );  // returns b2Vec {..} 
world = new Box2D.b2World( gravity ); // returns b2World {..} 

// Problem 1
bodyDef = new Box2D.b2BodyDef();   // returns b2BodyDef {..} 
body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);  // returns b2Body {..} 
massData = body.GetMassData();     // "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ptr' 
                                   // of undefined."

// Problem 2
contact = world.GetContactList();    // returns b2Contact {..}
manifold = contact.GetManifold();    // returns Object {..} NOT b2Manifold {..}
normal = manifold.get_localNormal(); // "TypeError: Object #<Object> has 
                                     // no method 'get_localNormal'."
```

How can I repair the use of these structures, and others like them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because those classes do not have a public constructor (or even any constructor at all). You'll need to add the constructors in the Box2D code.

Comment: Tried adding constructors, first: `b2MassData() {}`, then `b2MassData() { mass = 0.0f; center.Set(0.0f, 0.0f); I = 0.0f; }`. Neither seemed to make a difference. `Box2D.b2MassData` remains undefined.

Comment: You need to build the whole thing again using Emscripten, is what I meant to say, eg. download and compile the Emscripten source, use the makefile for the box2d sample to generate the js again from the box2d code you changed. I seem to recall it was not a trivial process...

Comment: Yup. That's what I did: downloaded emscipten, modified box2d source, modified makefile to point to enscripten, and rebuilt box2d.js with the `make` command. Compiles fine, just missing b2MassData still.

Comment: I think the constructors need to be public. Other than that, I have no clue. Try the emscripten people directly would probably give you more useful info than here tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Pretty sure you are correct. It's just a little finicky. Going to try taking the `embind` approach and hopefully that works a little more reliably.